# Pipeline as parallel command

Tags: bash, parallelism

Normally, pipelines in Unix are used to connect two commands and use the output of the first command as the input of the second command. However, I recently come up with the idea (which may not be new, but I didn't find much Googling) of using pipeline to run several commands in parallel, like this:

```
command1 | command2
```

This will invoke `command1` and `command2` in parallel **if `command2` does not read from standard input and `command1` does not write to standard outpu**t. A minimal example to illustrate this is (please run it in an interactive shell)

```
ls . -R 1>&2|ls . -R
```

My question is, are there any downsides to use pipeline to parallelize the execution of two commands in this way? Are there anything that I have missed in this idea?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: What wrong with `command1 & command2`?

Comment: I think if you replace `|` with `&` in my example and run in an interactive shell you can see the difference. Thank you anyway for your comment.

Comment: @WeijunZhou, pipeline is NOT parallelism stuff

Comment: @WeijunZhou At least on my system, replacing `|` with `&` in your example created exactly the same output. The difference is that `&` is specifically designed to execute several commands in parallel. A pipeline is simply the wrong tool for the task

Comment: @Fox Thank you for your comment. I should have clarified it. The difference can be seen when you send a keyboard interruption. As I have said in the original question, the main usage of this is in an interactive shell.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Command pipelines already run in parallel.  With the command:

```
command1 | command2
```

Both `command1` and `command2` are started.  If `command2` is scheduled and the pipe is empty, it blocks waiting to read.  If `command1` tries to write to the pipe and its full, `command1` blocks until there's room to write.  Otherwise, both `command1` and `command2` execute in parallel, writing to and reading from the pipe.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. So I can use this to parallelize commands without resorting to `parallel`, and there are no downsides. Or furthermore, this is normal practice. Is is fair to say that?

Comment: The behavior that you described is today's reality.  If you run `command1 | command2` where `command1` does not write to standard output and `command2` does not read from standard input, they will run in parallel.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, especially about the blocking mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

#### There are downsides...

1. you cannot see the output of `command1`
2. if `command2` doesn't read the output of `command1`, the latter will hang after writing some amount of output (I have seen 4K, but experimentally the limit is around 58K at least for a python process, see below). This may depend on the runtime used by `command1`.
3. if `command2` stops before `command1` and `command1` writes to its stdout, it will get `[Errno 32] Broken pipe`

#### Experiment:

cmd1

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

import sys,time
for i in range(64):
    print ("*"*1023,file=sys.stdout)
    print ("cmd1 here (%d)" % i,file=sys.stderr)
    time.sleep(.1)
print ("cmd1 exiting",file=sys.stderr)
```

cmd2

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

import sys,time
for i in range(16):
    print ("cmd2 here (%d)" % i,file=sys.stderr)
    time.sleep(1)
print ("cmd2 exiting",file=sys.stderr)
```

Run:

```
./cmd1 | ./cmd2
```

You will see:

- `cmd1` stalling at iteration 58 (because cmd2 never reads anything from its output)
- `cmd1` crashing (broken pipe) when cmd2 exits

So yes, maybe it can work. And maybe not.

Comment: Thank you for providing more insights to the problem. I have tested it and the result is like what you said if `cmd1` does write to standard output and I silently ignore it. However I see no problems if `cmd1` does not write to standard output at all (commenting out the line related to standard output), which is what I asked about in the original question.

Comment: If you want to, you can do `cmd >/dev/null | othercmd` so you don't have the blocking problem at least regarding the output of `cmd`. It looks rather silly, but works in bash, ksh and dash (not in zsh, but I think zsh splits the output to _both_ redirections)